# Music application missing from home screen on iOS

Tags: iphone, ios, music, music.app

I have an iPhone 7. For some reason, the music application is missing from my home screen. I have tried resetting to home screen layout but the music app still doesn't show up. I can see my music when I go into manage storage but can't play it on the phone.

Comment: Does the music app show up in settings normally? Are all the other apps ok?

Answer (score 2):

You have probably deleted it...
You can just reinstall it from the AppStore: https://appsto.re/us/-Jzdcb.i